# file_exists - PHP return dynamic public_html path

Tags: php, linux, file-exists

I am trying to find if a file exists in the public_html folder of the server.

1st try:

```
if ( file_exists('./local-config.php')) {
```

but this only works if the php file calling the above if statement is in the same folder... no good...

2nd try

```
if ( file_exists( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/local-config.php' ) ) {
```

doesn't work...

3rd try

```
if ( file_exists( 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/local-config.php' ) ) {
```

also doesn't work...

4th try

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] seems to fall short of my public_html folder!
```

Any ideas?

I can get this working if I put in the full path... e.g.

```
if ( file_exists( '/home/username/public_html/local-config.php' ) ) {
```

however this is no good to me because the script may be used on more than one server, so I need something generic.

Is it possible to get PHP to dynamically return the public_html path?

Comment: have you tried by just adding slash / like '/local-config.php'

Comment: I haven't tried that because it will look for a file called local-config.php in the root directory... e.g. the same directory that the home directory is in.

Comment: not really depending how your vhosts are set, for me it looks at public_html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a global variable across my application for this purpose. Similar to:

```
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Then I use this with the filename like:

```
ROOT . '/my_file.php'
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!!! If I have this running in the root of the public_html folder, then any file I include will also be able to use this global variable! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
// or just __DIR__ - it should be the same thing
```

which will return the full path of the file that's being called.  `__FILE__` is a "[magic constant](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)" in PHP.  From the help page:

```
The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of
the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2, __FILE__ always contains an
absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained
relative path under some circumstances.
```

With the resulting path, you should be able to figure out how to get exactly what you want.